# Clear ArrayList and do notifyDataSetChanged in adapter ListView from fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

How can I clear `ArrayList` and do `notifyDataSetChanged()` in adapter `ListView` from fragment?

This is my code in a shortcut:

```
public class ConnectionsFragment {
    public onClick() {
        // do clear data and notify it (from ListView), how?!
    }

    private class ArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<ConnectionsModel> data;

        // constructor saves received data to `data`
        // public view `getView()` displays it
    }
}
```

And I want to do clear data and notify I done it after `onClick()` in fragment class (or if it is even easier clear `ListView` until I read new data from API - so I want clear `ListView` when I do reading from API)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just create a public method in the adapter and make the variable private to protect it against unwanted edits or clearing:

```
private ArrayList<ConnectionsModel> mData;

public onClick() { 
    // do clear data and notify it (from ListView), how?! 
    clearData();
} 

public void clearData() {
    mData.clear();
    // do something else here if you want.  Like some kind of visual notification to the user
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

if your onclick method is in the fragment that's creating the adapter (call it mAdapter in this example), then the onclick would be:

```
public onClick() { 
    // do clear data and notify it (from ListView), how?! 
    mAdapter.clearData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `getView()` method is pulling from the `data` ArrayList, you should be able to call `data.clear();` and then `notifyDataSetChanged();` from within your `ArrayAdapter` class